# Looking for R version 3.5.2 for Mac

Tags: r

I updated my version of R not realizing that several packages are not compatible.  I'd like to go back to version 3.5.2 (for Mac), but I can't find it anywhere.  Anyone know where to find old versions?

Comment: Whoever closed this question last year as a duplicate is in error ... it is NOT a duplicate, the answers linked are for Windows version and do not address the Mac builds. The page https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ is confusingly written and only adds as a note "in small font" the link to the folder with older builds. It took me a while to understand what is going on and find those older builds myself. For example, for El Capitan they are here https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/base/

Comment: @predmod thanks for recognizing that!  It's frustrating that there's no way to 'challenge' the duplicate question when someone flags it.  I've had it happen a few times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get version 3.5.2 by modifying the link to download the present version (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-3.6.1.pkg), with the version number I'm interested in (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-3.5.1.pkg).  This started an automatic download.

Comment: Okay great, I actually did the same thing, but the previous comment didn't had the proper link 

Answer (score 0):

You can find and download all released versions of R for Mac [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/old/)

Comment: Thanks @Praveen, but unfortunately that only goes to version 3.3.3.

Comment: Here you go :)
http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/

Comment: Thanks again, but that just takes me to the present version (3.6.1).

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-3.5.2.pkg

Comment: nope, unfortunately not all of them, see also https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/base/